# How do I add a vertical slider to a simplemodal popup with default simplemodal settings?

Tags: jquery, slider, simplemodal

How do I add a vertical slider to a simplemodal popup with default simplemodal settings?  The popup is ~800px and the base div is 400px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the jQueryUI library which has all the options you propably need.

Check these links for more information:
for the dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
for the slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Jim

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, this demo should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericmmartin/r9BPZ/

It uses SimpleModal and the jQuery UI Slider.

Adjust the CSS/JS as needed.